# when I use facebook tools:deekmask, some errors came out and I can't find that's why

Tags: machine-learning, image-segmentation

I already installed proper packages, such as: torch, cocoapi, cudnn, cunn etc. And deployed deepmask correspondingly.

BUT, when I training model, typing: `th train.lua`, errors as follows:

```
xavier@xavier-ThundeRobot:/desired/absolute/path/to/deepmask$ th train.lua
-- ignore option rundir 
-- ignore option dm 
-- ignore option reload 
-- ignore option gpu    
-- ignore option datadir    
| running in directory /desired/absolute/path/to/deepmask/exps/deepmask/exp 
| number of paramaters trunk: 15198016  
| number of paramaters mask branch: 1608768 
| number of paramaters score branch: 526337 
| number of paramaters total: 17333121  
/home/xavier/torch/install/bin/luajit: ...e/xavier/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/threads/threads.lua:183: [thread 2 callback] /home/xavier/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/coco/CocoApi.lua:126: assertion failed!
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'assert'
    /home/xavier/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/coco/CocoApi.lua:126: in function '__init'
    /home/xavier/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/init.lua:91: in function </home/xavier/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/init.lua:87>
    [C]: in function 'CocoApi'
    /desired/absolute/path/to/deepmask/DataSampler.lua:25: in function '__init'
    /home/xavier/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/init.lua:91: in function </home/xavier/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/init.lua:87>
    [C]: in function 'DataSampler'
    /desired/absolute/path/to/deepmask/DataLoader.lua:36: in function </desired/absolute/path/to/deepmask/DataLoader.lua:30>
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    ...e/xavier/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/threads/threads.lua:234: in function 'callback'
    /home/xavier/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/threads/queue.lua:65: in function </home/xavier/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/threads/queue.lua:41>
    [C]: in function 'pcall'
    /home/xavier/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/threads/queue.lua:40: in function 'dojob'
    [string "  local Queue = require 'threads.queue'..."]:13: in main chunk
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    ...e/xavier/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/threads/threads.lua:183: in function 'dojob'
    ...e/xavier/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/threads/threads.lua:264: in function 'synchronize'
    ...e/xavier/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/threads/threads.lua:142: in function 'specific'
    ...e/xavier/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/threads/threads.lua:125: in function 'Threads'
    /desired/absolute/path/to/deepmask/DataLoader.lua:40: in function '__init'
    /home/xavier/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/init.lua:91: in function </home/xavier/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/init.lua:87>
    [C]: in function 'DataLoader'
    /desired/absolute/path/to/deepmask/DataLoader.lua:21: in function 'create'
    train.lua:101: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    ...vier/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:150: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00405d50
```

Pls Help me, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out myself!

The $DEEPMASK dir need high authority to access before, just `chmod 777 -R $DEEPMASK`, the problem solved.